# Showing a table is causing the div below to become smaller

Tags: html, css

Setup:

```
<div class="wrapper"> // width: 80%
    <div id"topDiv"></div> // display: table, hidden upon page load
    <div id="bottomDiv"></div>
</div>
```

I can't recreate this in JsFiddle, but when I show `topDiv`, the div on the bottom becomes smaller--its width decreases by 13px. The two divs are not set to 100% width--if I do set them then they are forced to stay the same size, but this causes them to go out of parent boundaries so they are left at `width: auto`.

What could be causing this and how would I fix it?

Comment: question is not clear. can you elaborate?

Comment: How do you perform "... I show `topDiv`"?

Comment: @matewka With either jquery or just by inspecting the element in the browser. As long as it's not `display: none`, `bottomDiv`'s width decreases.

Comment: Can you provide the complete CSS for those three elements (including `.wrapper`) and the jQuery code?

Comment: One possible reason, that I can think of, is that the content of the page gets longer, when showing the `topDiv`, making the browser display a scrollbar. This decreases the overall page width and with it the width of the  `.wrapper` because it is specified in percent. Might be something different, though. A [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be helpful.

Comment: @Jan I just spent so long making a fiddle and recreating the problem and was about to type what I found out. But thanks for confirming the problem! Didn't think it would be something that simple. http://jsfiddle.net/ZT2ZF/